# How to display only non-null values using an aggregate query?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create a query to list the average price of books of a certain type, but only if the average is above 500.

This is my current query:

```
SELECT TYPE,
       IF(Avg(pages) > 500, Round(Avg(pages)), NULL) AS "Average Pages"
FROM   titles
GROUP  BY TYPE;
```

Which gives me this:

```
+------------+---------------+
| type       | Average Pages |
+------------+---------------+
| biography  |          NULL |
| children   |          NULL |
| computer   |          1226 |
| history    |          NULL |
| psychology |           512 |
+------------+---------------+
```

This of course is including the NULL values, when I'm trying to achieve this:

```
+------------+---------------+
| type       | Average Pages |
+------------+---------------+
| computer   |          1226 |
| psychology |           512 |
+------------+---------------+
```

Though I'm not sure of the best way to do this. I've messed with WHERE  statements, but have had no such luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
SELECT type, AVG(pages) AS "Average Pages"
FROM titles
GROUP BY type
HAVING AVG(pages) >= 500;
```

Answer (score 1):

for aggregated  function you can filter the result using having

```
SELECT TYPE, Avg(pages) AS "Average Pages"
FROM   titles
GROUP  BY TYPE;
HAVING  Avg(pages) > 500
```

Comment: Ah, I was missing the HAVING keyword. Cheers!

Comment: Values under 500 are not shown with this solution. That's not coresponding to the question @Grav asked.

Comment: @Meloman it is, the title says "How to display only non-null values". However the syntax above is incorrect, `HAVING` goes after `GROUP BY` not before

Comment: You're right @Gab for the placement of having AND the `> 500` is not equal to `NOT NULL`, so this solution is not to be the voted one.

Comment: I think its a question of how the question is formulated. In OP's query you have `IF(Avg(pages) > 500, Round(Avg(pages)), NULL)` so he is replacing rows with AVG < 500 with `NULL` so I believe that when OP says "How to display only non-null values" he means "I don't want rows with AVG < 500". My answer is better because the SQL syntax is valid unlike this answer but OP chose the one with the incorrect syntax...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with `IS NOT NULL` like this :

```
SELECT 
    `type`,
    IF(Avg(`pages`) > 500, Round(Avg(`pages`)), NULL) AS `avg_pages`
FROM `titles`
WHERE `avg_pages` IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY `type`;
```